# center div inside parent div whilst also covering another child div

Tags: css, reactjs

I am making a chess game and when a player wins I need the component
 to show up in the center of the screen to say , White Wins Etc,

is just:

```html
<div> 
  <p> White Wins <p/>
<div/>
```

shares the parent div with  , thought I want  to show right in the centre of board vertically and horizontally.

and I can't just put  inside the  component, as it would be a lot of work passing values down to it etc.

```html
<div className="board-container">
  <playerWinsAlert/>
  <Board/>
</div>
```

Comment: add a screenshot

Comment: Did my answer work? If so please accept it.

Comment: please share your codes for better answers.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.board {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.message-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }
```

```html
 <div className="board-container">
  <Board/>
  <div class="message-container">
    <Message/>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: no sorry that did not work

Comment: is .board meant to be .board-container ?

Comment: No its meant to be whatever class you use for <Board/>, if this code does not work its because of outside factors that you haven't shown could you please add more code to your question.